# WITH clause performance issues; Rewrite into While Loop?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am currently looking at areas to optimize some of our stored procedures and I have run across in performance analysis, a chunk of SQL in a stored proc that is just performing terribly.  I've done some research and I've read that using the with clause when you don't have unique records is a no-no so I would like to rewrite this but I am having troubles.  I'm thinking a while loop may be my best bet in order to achieve the result I am after but I cannot get the hierarchy of the data to populate correctly (specifically the [level] field).  Here is the chunk of SQL I am trying to rewrite.  Any suggestions/ideas would be tremendously appreciated.

```
;WITH RuleChart (
  RuleID, 
  RuleDetailID, 
  RuleUnitGroupID, 
  ParentRuleUnitGroupID, 
  [Level],
  IsNextRuleUnitGroupAvailable
) AS (

  SELECT 
    DISTINCT RD.RuleID, 
    RD.RuleDetailID, 
    RD.RuleUnitGroupID, 
    RD.ParentRuleUnitGroupID, 
    0 AS [Level],
    RD.IsNextRuleUnitGroupAvailable
  FROM #TtblRuleDetail RD
  WHERE 
    RD.RuleID IN (
        SELECT RuleID 
        FROM #TtblRule 
        WHERE ResultID IN (
          SELECT ResultID
          FROM #TtblResultUnit
        )
    )
    AND RD.ParentRuleUnitGroupID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      RD.RuleID, 
      RD.RuleDetailID, 
      RD.RuleUnitGroupID, 
      RD.ParentRuleUnitGroupID, 
      [Level] + 1,
      RD.IsNextRuleUnitGroupAvailable
    FROM 
      #TtblRuleDetail RD
      INNER JOIN RuleChart RC 
        ON
          RD.ParentRuleUnitGroupID = RC.RuleUnitGroupID
          AND RD.RuleID=RC.RuleID
)
```

Comment: I formatted your code.

Comment: Sorry about that and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the size of the temp tables that you're utilizing.  How big are they, do you create any indexes on them prior to this WITH clause?  Just from looking at the statement it looks like you could create an index on #TtblRuleDetail.RuleID, and another on #TtblRuleDetail.ParentRuleUnitGroupID.  That would probably help the performance, but a better approach would probably be to eliminate the temp tables altogether, because you may already have indexes on the source tables that would help speed up the query.

Comment: I agree, eliminiating the temp tables would be a big help.  Unfortunately in the current architecture, these temp tables used above are loaded from XML that gets passed into the proc.  There are no indexes created on the temp tables so I can try doing that as well.  These tables at most will have 6-8,000 records but it is definitely a performance hog on the system.